# Changing Username in Database

Tags: php, mysql, database, account

```
<?php
    if($_SESSION['id']) {
                $result = mysql_query("
    SELECT
      id,usr,pass,email,dt,priv
    FROM
      tz_members
    WHERE
      usr = '" . $_SESSION['usr'] . "'
");
$done=0;
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                {
                echo '<div class="roundbox"><div class="grey"><h2>Change Username</h2><br>Below you can view your current informations.<br>This page allows you to change your username!<br><table>';
                echo "<tr><td><strong>Unique ID:</strong></td><td>" . $row['id'] . "</td><em><td>(Can't be seen by others!)</em></td></tr>";
                echo "<tr><td><strong>Username:</strong></td><td>" . $row['usr'] . "</td><em><td>(Can be seen by others!)</em></td></tr></table><br>";
                echo '<form action="edituser.html" method="post">
                        <div class="grey">New Username:</div><br>
                        <input type="text" name="newuser" size="20" maxlength="40" value=""><br><br>
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Change"></div>
                      </form></table>'; }
if($_POST['submit']=='Change') {
$usr = $_SESSION['usr'];
$query="SELECT usr FROM tz_members WHERE usr = '$usr'";
$st=mysql_query($query);
$recs=mysql_num_rows($st);
$row=mysql_fetch_object($st);
$newuser = $_POST['newuser'];
mysql_query("UPDATE tz_members 
SET 
$row->$usr 
WHERE 
usr = $usr");
$done=1;
}

if($done == 1)
Header("Location: login_panel/userchanged.html");
}
    else echo '<div class="roundbox"><h2>You must be <a href="login.html">logged in</a> to change your username!</h2></div>';
    ?>
```

I have the following code. I'm trying to make it so when one completes the 'newuser' field, and presses the 'Change' button, his username (username is written in $_SESSION['usr']) gets changed to the user in the 'newuser' field. But it keeps failing, further more I have the following error:

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in /home/u594115708/public_html/edituser.html on line 129

Comment: Which line is the line 129?

Comment: $query="SELECT usr FROM tz_members WHERE usr = '$usr'";

Comment: try this $query="SELECT usr FROM tz_members WHERE usr = '".$usr."'";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE tz_members SET $row->$usr WHERE usr = $usr");
```

To this:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE tz_members SET usr = '{$newusr}' WHERE usr = '{$usr}'");
```

Also add at the begin of the php script:

```
session_start();
```

Comment: Your query atleast does a part of the job:
It selects the user, but it sets it's value to... nothing, what could be the problem ?

Comment: $newuser = $_POST['newuser']; bellow that line try with a var_dump($newuser); and post the result pls

Comment: Did the var_dump, $newuser has got the value of the field.

Answer (score 1):

`$_SESSION['usr']` is an object and not a scalar variable. The value you are looking for is inside that object. I am *guessing* it can be reached by using:

```
$_SESSION['usr']->user;
```

So that line of code should look like this:

```
$usr = $_SESSION['usr']->user;
```

Comment: This line causes the problem:
$query="SELECT usr FROM tz_members WHERE usr = '$usr'";
The first query is good as I'm using it on the members page too.

Answer (score 0):

`$usr` is not being overwritten because your `$_SESSION` variables are not accessible, since you did not call `session_start()` at the beginning of your script.

Add `session_start()` to the beginning, like so:

```
<?php

session_start();

...
```

Comment: I have a separate include for that, thank you for your time anyway :)